# Table with a lot of fields for monthly report

Tags: vba, ms-access

In CPA office (acounting) I have a table with basic fields including customer names and ID ....and other details, and beside that in the same table for each customer I have 12 fields (for 12 months), it is yes/no data and it is needed to check if the customer has done the monthly based report or not. another yes/no fields for the annual report .... and others for other purposes.
I have a form tracking the monthly reports, and form for the annual reports.... and so on.
the problem is that I cannot add more fields i got the error (Property value is too large when I am adding filed in table formatting)
all the relations between the customers and the reports is one to one!!!!
How to get over this problem, what is the better structure?  thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

By design, Microsoft Access is limited to 255 fields in a table. This includes fields that you have added to the table but subsequently deleted (although you can "reclaim" these by doing a compact of the database).

To be quite honest, a table with even 50 fields is probably not designed properly.

You need to look at the design of your database and table, and work out how to restructure it. There is not enough information in your post to give detailed instructions, but consider:

- A table for customers, including an autonumber primary key;
- A table that lists the monthly/annual reports, again including a primary key;
- A "junction" table that is used to hold infomation about the reports generated for customers. This would have the customer ID and report ID as well as other relevant information, such as when the report was generated.

Regards,